# Issue with "ureadahead" and "util-linux" packages

Tags: package-management, dpkg, configuration, ureadahead

My system is encountering issues while processing packages `ureadahead` and `util-linux`:

```
root@sait32:/home/sait32/Downloads# sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package ureadahead (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ureadahead
 util-linux
```

Can anyone please help on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the error message's instructions:

```
dpkg: error processing package ureadahead (--configure):  package is
 in a very bad inconsistent state; you should  reinstall it before
 attempting configuration
```

Try: `sudo apt install --reinstall ureadahead`

Do the same for util-linux.